YA sci-fi fantasy novel from the 80s or 90s about boy who goes to a boarding school where students wear some kind of mind control device
I'm looking for a young adult sci-fi fantasy novel from the 80s or 90s about a boy who goes to a boarding school where students wear some kind of mind-control device.
The cover may be yellow with a castle on it, if that helps. The boy's parents are moving to outer space, and their son is sent to a boarding school with a medieval theme? The students wear these headpieces or crowns that are some kind of advanced technology or mind control. The boy quickly partners up with a young woman who becomes a co-protagonist, but he is the initial character. Does anyone know what this book is?
